# Sticky header with a switch (like Hongkiat)

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I'm creating the sticky header using waypoints in this tutorial http://www.webtutorialplus.com/sticky-header-on-scroll-jquery/

But how do I create a header which 'swaps'?

Example: If you visit http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ and scroll down the header which scrolls, is not actually an element which is originally visible on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3JZL7/)

```
$('.showafterthis').waypoint(function() {
  if ($(".header2").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".header2").slideDown(100);
  } else {
        $(".header2").slideUp(100);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this method is superior to the one I posted, BUT if you set the slideDown/Up time to something like 500, and then scroll up and down fast, you can confuse the system and reverse the second header.

Answer (score 1):

They are actually two separate nav. bars.

I would create another one and hide it on load by moving it off the top of the screen.
Put it outside of any inner html with a relative position, of course.

```
<div id="nav2">Your links and jazz</div>
```

and in the CSS:

```
#nav2 { style:your; bar:!; }
.sticky-wrapper { position:absolute; top:-50px;  }
```

The sticky wrapper line is very important.  This is the div around the navigation bar, and this is the line that gets the positioning, NOT the nav2 line.

For your javascript:

```
$('#nav2').waypoint('sticky', {
    offset: -300 // how far from top
});
```

You can fool around with the offset to get it where you want.

Good luck!